# Regex datatable columns character ignoring

Tags: html, sql-server, regex, database

I'm trying to compare to columns tables, but it seems that I'm loosing data 'cause the following regex : ^c%

To make it simple I got **cprovince** ( table 1) and **Province** ( table 2) and normal output I got :

cprovince  'NULL'

Province 'Does not Exists in table1'

How ? technically I'm doing this : `cte1.Column_Name  = cte2.Column_Name and  cte2.Column_Name LIKE '(?<=|^)[^c][-A-zZ0-9 ]+'`

**How can I improve my regex  to ignore 'c'( begin by c for char best practice)  from cColumnName ?**

Following this link it works : https://rubular.com/r/LZpVwcFJLk

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Negative Lookahead* `(?!)`. So I'd go for this regex

```
(?!c)[\w]+
```

to ignore the first `c` encountered from the left (need not be the start of the line) and match everything else until we encounter a non-word character.

If you want to allow `c` to happen anywhere but in the start position of the line,
then you should use

```
(?!^c)[\w]+
```

where `^` is the quantifier for the start position of lines.

Answer (score 0):

No need of regex. Use

```sql
LIKE 'c%'
```

You will have a "match" if the string starts with `c` and then has any text. So, you will match `cprovince`.